# Who is the local authority to decide if a candidate eligible to be on a ballot?

Tags: florida, elections

Given a 14th amendment challenge in Minnesota: https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/14th-amendment-challenges-grow-trumps-qualification-office-campaign/story?id=103118677

It is my understanding that the [elections are administered at the state / county level.](https://ballotpedia.org/Who_runs_elections_in_the_United_States%3F_(2020))  Presumably they control who is / is not on the ballot.

If a state must be picked for a concrete example: please to use Florida.

Who is the local authority to decide if a candidate eligible to be on a ballot?

Answer (score 2):

In every state, conducting elections is the job of the Secretary of State. There are forms to fill out, fees to pay, and so on. It is possible that in filing the application, a person may reveal their disqualification or even ask for a determination of eligibility ([Hassan v. Colorado](https://casetext.com/case/hassan-v-colorado-5)). In lieu of a court order (initiated by somebody's lawsuit to prevent a person from running for public office), the initial decision would come from the Sec'y of State. Thereafter, it would be up to the courts.

There may be in intermediate government body such as an "Elections Commission", but in Florida it has [no power over candidate qualifications](http://www.fec.state.fl.us/), only the power to investigate alleged violations of certain Florida statutory requirements. If a candidate makes a false representation about military service, they can be fined, and the Commission can assess such a fine.